# What does tor proxy and tor directory stores?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, onion-routing, directory

Does tor proxy includes keys that it shares with all tor nodes for encryption?who stores information about all tor nodes in the route?

Answer (score 2):

**No One** stores the keys of the Onion Routers making the Virtual Circuit except the Tor Client.

The Tor Client download the list of Onion Routers online. It creates the virtual circuit **incrementally** by selecting three nodes out of that list. What I mean by incrementally here is that it selects one node and gets its public key and use this key to contact second node and so forth. Thus in the end it's only the client who knows about all the nodes consisting the virtual circuit while all Onion Routers know only the  two nodes adjacent to them.
For more details check this paper, [The TOR data communication system](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6896565).